# rig shifts upon IK application

Tags: rigging

I'm trying to create a simple low-poly rig for some testing and I'd like to create it manually. Right now I have a problem where even though my IK bone has no parent and Deform is unchecked, trying to create any kind of IK shifts the bones, sometimes quite majorly. How do I solves this?

[image]

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Definitely, here you are! [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5513" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5513/)

Comment: if you choose the Palm_L_Ik as the target of the Forearm_L, the Forearm_L will stick to the head of the Palm_L_IK, that's why it moves when you switch to Pose mode, if you don't want this to happen, you need, in Edit mode, to put the tail of Forearm_L at the same point than the head of Palm_L_Ik... does it solve your problem or are you talking about something else? By the way, the Deform option is to prevent the mesh to be affected by the bone, it has nothing to do with your problem (I mean if I understood it correctly)

Comment: @moonboots Ah, I see. Yup, you got it, thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you choose the *Palm_L_Ik* as the target of the *Forearm_L*, the *Forearm_L* will stick to the head of the *Palm_L_IK*, that's why it moves when you switch to *Pose* mode, if you don't want this to happen, you need, in *Edit* mode, to put the tail of *Forearm_L* at the same point than the head of *Palm_L_Ik*...

By the way, the Deform option is to prevent the mesh to be affected by the bone, it has nothing to do with your problem